# What kind of verb is נִשְׁחָ֑תָה in Genesis 6:12

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible

In Genesis 6:12 we read in the Hebrew text that the verb נִשְׁחָ֑תָה is preceded by a demonstrative particle וְהִנֵּ֣ה and suceeded by the noun כִּֽי which is not a direct object. In translations, it reads like, "it was corrupted..." So i think that it neither has a subject nor an object (correct me if I'm wrong), so what kind of verb would that be? And how does it function in such a state?

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the verb נִשְׁחָתָה (*nischata*), “it had been ruined,” is the preceding הָאָרֶץ (*ha-aretz*), “the earth.”

> <sup>12</sup> God looked upon **the earth**, and behold, **it** had been ruined.

The antecedent of the pronoun “it” is the noun “the earth.”

כִּי is not a noun. In this context, it functions as a conjunction meaning “because, for, since.” It introduces the reason why the earth had been ruined.

> <sup>12</sup> And God looked upon the earth, and, behold, it had been ruined, **because** all flesh had ruined his way upon the earth.